# Autoresizing mask on webview not making any difference

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, autoresizingmask

How do I add autoresizing mask to a webview.

I have tried this

```
[self.webView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
[self.webView reload];
```

The webview doesn't change size depending on the modal dialog size. If the orientation changes then I change the size of the modal dialog so that the keyboard doesn't go over the text box. Though the webview size doesn't change.

**I want the webview to stay at the top and the height to be reduced when the height of the modal dialog is less.**

I have also tried resizing it manually but the webview doesn't want to change size. THis is me trying to change it manually

```
self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.webView.frame.origin.x, self.webView.frame.origin.y, self.webView.frame.size.width, 0);
[self.webView reload];
```

Comment: normally a "modal dialog" would imply a modal view controller which would replace the contents on your screen - could you be more detailed about what you mean when you say "modal dialog"

Comment: A dialog that is not full screen that appears on top of the current screen and anything the modal dialog does not block can still be seen but darkened out.

Comment: Explain the view hierarchy. How are you darkening out? (this usually entails a view that covers the entire screen) Is the web view **in** the "dialog".  Tell us the classes you are using.  Have you used the debugger to see the frame sizes of the various views?

Answer (score 3):

```
[self.webView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
```

indicates that the view can change it's height to keep the same distance between it's bottom and it's parent view controller bottom one

```
self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.webView.frame.origin.x, self.webView.frame.origin.y, self.webView.frame.size.width, 0);
```

indicates you want to change the dimension of your view so that it keeps the same origin x, y, the same width but get a height of 0...

what you might want to do is 
     CGRect parentFrame = self.webView.superview.frame
     self.webview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, parentFrame.size.width, parentFrame.size.height);

```
 [self.webView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
```

you webview should then always fill completely it's parent view

N.B. 
    [self.webview reload];
doesn't redraw the webview but reload the html page

Comment: `[self.webView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];` indicates the view will try to maintain its constant hight while varying the distance to the bottom of it's parent view.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your keyboard is being displayed over the webView's parent view.  If the parent view doesn't change sizes, the webView will have nothing to do.

Also, i suspect what you really want is:

```
self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: I change the parent view in order to make the modal dialog shorter but wider when the orientation changes. So the size of the parent view does change.